# How to upgrade Git on windows?

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, msysgit

I'm currently running git version 1.8.0-preview20121022 on windows 7.  I'd like to upgrade to the current latest version 1.9.4-preview20140611.  I downloaded the installer `Git-1.9.4-preview20140611.exe` and ran it.   It complains that I'd need to close Windows Explorer:

[image]

Clicking next just brings up an error.  How am I supposed to upgrade git?  Am I supposed to open the task manager and find that pid and kill it?  Also my existing git installation is not in the standard program files folder, is the installer going to ask where I want to install git (so far it hasn't)?

Comment: To answer the other part of my question, the installer never asked where I wanted to install git but did correctly find my existing installation (which was not in the standard Program Files folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - reboot. You just may have a rogue run-away explorer process. It is, however, a tiny bit safer to reboot than to just kill it by its PID IMHO.

If that doesn't help - log into Windows with your admin user. With any luck it won't have the shell integration running and will not have the needed files in-use. Install your new GiT from that admin account.

If that still doesn't help... Time to use the "kill by PID" way and force your way through!

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks the reboot worked!  Git's always seemed like a more-complicated-than-average install on Windows so my first thought was that it was something more involved.

Comment: I'm just glad there **is** a Windows port of GiT:)